# Time ranges with 24 hour formatting

Tags: c#, timespan

I need to test if two values falls within a shift. I have a start time and an end time of an activity, I need to ensure that the start time is not before the shift start time and that the end time is not after the shift end time. The problem is that the shift runs from 22:00 to 06:00. I'm currently using Timespan variables but and my simple if statement doesn't get the job done:

```
if (start >= shiftStartTime & end <= shiftEndTime)
```

I understand why it doesn't work but I don't know how to approach this. I also tried:

```
if (start.Ticks > shiftStartTime.Ticks && end.Ticks < shiftEndTime.Ticks)
```

Based on specifications made by the user (this would not have been my choice) I have 4 combo boxes which are then used in combination. This is my very crude method of getting the start and end times selected by the user:

```
string endHour = (cmbEndHour.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
string endMin = (cmbEndMin.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
string endEvent = (endHour + ":" + endMin);
TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse(endEvent);
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: how are you creating `start` , like this `var start = TimeSpan.FromHours(22);` ?

Comment: I updated the question to show how I get the values. I cannot change the controls unfortunately.

Comment: try using  `Datetime`, instead of `Timespan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
if ((start >= shiftStartTime || start <= shiftEndTime) && (end >= shiftStartTime || end <= shiftEndTime))
```